# How to place images in Android drawables

Tags: android, layout

Android Asus tablet is acessing images from android `mdpi` drawable and also `lgoptimusp509` is accessing images from same mdpi folder.

Due to this I am facing alignment problems. How to fix this?

Comment: what problem are you facing exactly?

Comment: what type of alignment prolem?

Comment: my asus tablet is 10 inches and lg optimus is of 320X480 so if i place icons of 150pxX150px they are appearing large in lg and best sutable for asus.if i place 72pxX72px they are appering small for tablet and best for lg.. this my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide resources for multiple resolution and densities.
so you have to put same images in hdpi,mdpi and ldpi drawable folder with diff resolutions.
and write this code in android manifest.xml

```
<supports-screens 
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should provide resources for multiple resolution and densities by following the guidelines at [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

There is also a tool from Google [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html) where you can upload your icons,menu icons,action bar icons and it will properly scale them for ldpi,mdpi,hdpi. You should also have a look at that.

Answer (score 1):

Devices access the images according to their density.so you should put same images in hdpi,mdpi and ldpi drawable folder with different resolution,so that those images will fit in respective devices.